# How to make HTML5 drag and drop work like jQuery UI draggable?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two major deal breakers with HTML5 drag and drop. The first is that I only want to see the ghost element. The second is I want to have the normal cursor while the element is being dragged.

[image]

```
<div draggable="true">DRAG TEST</div>
```

[fiddle (webkit only)](http://jsfiddle.net/3erdT/1/)

Comment: The cursor I believe is set like that because you have a dedicated drop point set. That being said try having the entire page droppable as well. Depending on the intended effect could be a simple work around.

Comment: Well that sort of makes the cursor part work. It's still not the normal cursor and it only seems to be working in random areas (body is the gray area). http://jsfiddle.net/3erdT/22/

Comment: you could try setting the css curosor attribute for the square your are moving to override it. That may not work though but worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

You can set cursor style while dragging by,

```
       $(".class").draggable({
        revert: true,
        revertDuration: 1000,
        cursor: "move"
    });

        cursor: "move",  cursor: "auto", cursor: "none"
```